# How do I calculate percentage in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I calculate percentage across rows with respect to a column?

I'm working on a table with three columns:

- Column one - date (varchar)(expressed in words).
- Column two - amount(int)
- Column three - goods_services (varchar).

There where situations where a particular date was entered more than once because of different values for goods_services.
So how then do I query the table to calculate the percentage of what each goods_services contribute to the total amount with respect to amount.
E.g savings 10%...., Feeding 20% etc.

I have tried For instance:

```
SELECT 
   Goods_services,
   SUM(Amount)OVER(PARTITION BY Goods_services)/SUM(Amount)*100
FROM....
ORDER BY.....
```

And few other query related to GROUP BY and PARTITION BY syntax but I can't seem to get the desired results I want.

Comment: You are going to get integer division like that, you need to do `* 100.0 / SUM(Amount) OVER...`

Comment: Thanks so much bruh.Was wandering why my result did not sum up to a hundred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can carry this out by:

- aggregating on amounts by Goods_services
- dividing your amount by the application of window function `SUM() OVER()` over your `SUM(amount)` generated field.

```
SELECT Goods_services,
       100.0 * SUM(Amount) / SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER() AS perc
FROM tab
GROUP BY Goods_services
```

Comment: Thank you   .It worked perfectly.Was wondering why the "SUM" syntax was used twice on the window function and  why the 100 comes before the aggregation,not after.Care to explain?

Comment: Sure. `SUM(Amount)` will compute the amounts for each Goods_services. When you use SUM(SUM(Amount)), it will cast the total sum: that's what we're trying to do, dividing each sum with the overall total sum. Concerning the 100 before the aggregation, you can also move it at the end of the whole expression in my specific code, and would achieve the same output.